# ruby on rails nested form create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have user model that has many reviews, and each review has many replies.

I want to allow the user to reply under a review.

In a profile page (coming from a profile controller and show action), I want to be able to create replies.

```
<div class="reply-box d-none" id="reply-box">
    <%= form_with(model: Reply, url: new_user_review_reply_path(@user, @review)) do |reply| %>
    <%= reply.hidden_field :user_id, value: @user %>
    <%= reply.hidden_field :review_id, value: @review %>
    <%= reply.text_field :reply_content%>
    <div class="comment-box-btns mb-5">
        <%= reply.submit "submit", class: 'submit-btn d-inline-block ml-2 float-right'%>
        <div class="cancel-btn d-inline-block float-right">cancel</div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Here is the route.rb

```
resources :users do
  resources :reviews do
    resources :replies
  end
end
```

Here is the reply controller:

```
class RepliesController < ApplicationController
def new
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @reivew = @user.reviews.find(params[:review_id])
  @reply = @reivew.replies.new
end

def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @reivew = @user.reviews.find(params[:review_id])
  @reply = @reivew.replies.create!(reply_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to(profile_path(param[:user_id]))}
    format.js
  end
end

private
def reply_params
  params.require(:reply).permit(
    :reply_content,
    :user_id,
    :review_id
  )
end
end
```

I don't know how to set up the "form_with". So far it just says

```
undefined method `reply_content' for #<Class:0x007f8c7396aaa8>
```

reply_content is the field in reply I want to create using the text_area.

I am very confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already intitilize `@reply = @reivew.replies.new` in new action so you should use this `@reply` object with reply form, also i don't think that you need not to explicitly provide `value: user_id` and `value: review_id`

```
<div class="reply-box d-none" id="reply-box">
    <%= form_for @reply, url: new_user_review_reply_path(@user, @review) do |reply| %>
    <%= reply.hidden_field :user_id %>
    <%= reply.hidden_field :review_id %>
    <%= reply.text_field :reply_content%>
    <div class="comment-box-btns mb-5">
        <%= reply.submit "submit", class: 'submit-btn d-inline-block ml-2 float-right'%>
        <div class="cancel-btn d-inline-block float-right">cancel</div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```